# Finding element pairs from two sets that have a predefined relation

Tags: python, set, compare, element

I have two lists

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list2 = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

I know from before that some of these elements are related through another list

```
ref_list = [
   ['d', 'f'], ['a', 'e'], ['b', 'g'], ['c', 'f'], ['a', 'g'],
   ['a', 'f'], ['b', 'e'], ['b', 'f'], ['c', 'e'], ['c', 'g']
]
```

I would like to quickly identify the two groups from `list1` and `list2` which have all the possible pairs `[list1 element, list2 element]` in `ref_list`.
In this case the solution would be

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```

I can think of some ways to do this for such small lists but need help if `list1`, `list2` and `ref_list` have thousands of elements each.

Comment: Your expected output `['a','b','c']` and `['e','f','g']` does not cover the pair `['d','f']`.

Comment: Good catch. Let me edit the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set inclusion seems pretty fast.

```
import random
import string

list1 = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in xrange(9999)]
# len(list1) == 9999    
list2 = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in xrange(9999)]
# len(list2) == 9999
ref_list = [[random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters), random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters) + random.choice(string.ascii_letters)] for _ in xrange(9999)]
# len(ref_list) == 9999

refs1 = set([t[0] for t in ref_list])
# CPU times: user 2.45 ms, sys: 348 µs, total: 2.8 ms
# Wall time: 2.2 ms
# len(refs1) == 9656 for this run

refs2 = set([t[1] for t in ref_list])
# CPU times: user 658 µs, sys: 3.92 ms, total: 4.58 ms
# Wall time: 4.02 ms
# len(refs2) == 9676 for this run

list1_filtered = [v for v in list1 if v in refs1]
# CPU times: user 1.19 ms, sys: 4.34 ms, total: 5.53 ms
# Wall time: 3.76 ms
# len(list1_filtered) == 702 for this run

list2_filtered = [v for v in list2 if v in refs2]
# CPU times: user 3.05 ms, sys: 4.29 ms, total: 7.33 ms
# Wall time: 4.51 ms
# len(list2_filtered) == 697 for this run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the elements from each pair in `ref_list` to sets `set1` and `set2`, then use `list1 = list(set1)` and `list2 = list(set2)`. Sets contain no duplicates, and this should be fast for thousands of elements since `e in s1` for sets takes [O(1) time on average](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: Thanks but that would not work. Unlike the example I gave, the solution for larger list1 and list2  would have multiple group pairs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` to generate counts for items in `ref_list` and use them to filter out items in the two lists that do not occur more than once:

```
from collections import Counter
[[i for i in lst if counts.get(i, 0) > 1] for lst, ref in zip((list1, list2), zip(*ref_list)) for counts in (Counter(ref),)]
```

This returns:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g']]
```